# Drag, Drop and Clone - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I am a teacher trying to make a simple Flash AS3 game where students can drag any letter from a-z(movieclips) out to the middle of the stage to create words.

I am a total amateur with Flash and so using code snippets, I have been successful in allowing users to drag and drop letters but what I would really like is for users to be able to drag and drop a letter leaving the original letter movieclip in place and clone a new one as many times as is necessary.

Is anyone able to help me with the AS3 I would need to achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: I have just found this SWF which provides a perfect example of what I am trying to achieve: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/418650/hype/08_Using_5_Frames.swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick sample. [FLA](http://bitlox.com/misc/sample-drag-drop/sample1.fla) | [SWF](http://bitlox.com/misc/sample-drag-drop/sample1.swf)

**CODE:**

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

for (var i=1; i<5; i++)
{
    this["object" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStart);
    this["object" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
}    

var sx = 0,sy = 0;

function onStart(e)
{
    sx = e.currentTarget.x;
    sy = e.currentTarget.y;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}

function onStop(e)
{
    if (e.target.dropTarget != null && 
    e.target.dropTarget.parent == dest)
    {
        var objectClass:Class = 
        getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget)) as Class;
        var copy:MovieClip = new objectClass();
        this.addChild(copy);
        copy.x = e.currentTarget.x;
        copy.y = e.currentTarget.y;
    }

    e.currentTarget.x = sx;
    e.currentTarget.y = sy;
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Hoping you could take it ahead & turn into something useful for your kids.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please do check the green tick if this answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @loxxy. It's working very well so far, except for one thing. I want the kids to be able to drag and drop letters around on the main part of the stage after they have taken them from the base on either the left or right. Is there a way I can add this functionality with AS3? [SWF](http://www.jamesjardine.net/ict/sample.swf) [FLA] (http://www.jamesjardine.net/ict/sample.fla)

Answer (score 0):

first, you can use a property for your letters called like "`type`" and "`letter`" for assuming is it original or a copy and which letter is it.

then initialize an empty object variable to use when clicked

```
var draggingObj:Object;
```

then you can check if user clicking on orginal letter to make a copy and move or clicking a copy just to move

```
if (Letter(clickedLetter).type == "original")
{
draggingObj = new Letter();
draggingObj.type = "copy";
draggingObj.letter = Letter(clickedLetter).letter;
}
else draggingObj = Letter(clickedLetter);

draggingObj.x = mousex;
draggingObj.y = mousey;
```

if you cannot implement this codeflow to your codeflow, you can write your own code here so we can help you properly