# drag and drop actionscript issue, how to fix?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop, drag

I have a problem with my ActionScript drag and drop + clone. An object gets stuck after a few instances, when it overlaps with another instance. Each object is a movieclip, that is vector graphic imported form Adobe Illustrator.

What must i change to make it not get stuck? I borrowed from this stackoverflow question: [Drag, Drop and Clone - Flash AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674358/drag-drop-and-clone-flash-as3)

Here is my actionscript:

```
 import flash.display.MovieClip;

 for (var i = 1; i < 27; i++)
 {
    this["object" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStart);
    this["object" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
 }

 var sx = 0, sy = 0;

 function onStart(e)
 {
    sx = e.currentTarget.x;
    sy = e.currentTarget.y;
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
 }

 function onStop(e)
 {
    if (e.target.dropTarget != null && 
        e.target.dropTarget.parent == dest)
    {
        var objectClass:Class = 
        getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget)) as Class;
        var copy:MovieClip = new objectClass();
        this.addChild(copy);
        copy.x = e.currentTarget.x;
        copy.y = e.currentTarget.y;
    }

    e.currentTarget.x = sx;
    e.currentTarget.y = sy;
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You start with 26 objects on the stage already?

Comment: Most apps when you do a drag and drop, you create the copy on mouse down and drag the copy.

Comment: Show me a screenshot of stuck.

Comment: isn't e.target.dropTarget.parent simply e.target